# Python working with os.system

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code below:

```
def display_keyboard(*_):
    os.system(r'start " " C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe')
```

The problem is that when this code runs, I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\Program.
```

I have an issue working out withespaces so that it search for the entire file

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to read the full documentation for that function?

Comment: Have you tried `os.system(r'start " " "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"')`?

Comment: Put the path name in quotes.

Comment: Do you want to wait for the process to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `subprocess.Popen()` or `subprocess.run()` is almost always a better choice than `os.system()`.

```
import subprocess

def display_keyboard(*args):
    return subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe')
```

Some reasons include:

- No need to worry about escaping arguments;
- Much more control over the child process, for example over stdout, stderr and stdin streams;
- `wait()` and `terminate()` methods, etc.

Comment: An explanation would help, the list is also redundant and not sure what `*args` is doing

Comment: I included `*args` because the original code included a variable argument input. I just gave it the more conventional name.

Comment: run is also only in python >= 3.5

Comment: You could use `subprocess.check_call()` if you need to wait for `TabTip.exe` to return and it works on Python 2.5+.

Answer (score 0):

you should instead use

```
os.startfile("C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe")
```

I think

Comment: This is probably a more explicit answer than mine as it does exactly what is says it does rather than relying on other programs.

Answer (score 0):

When running commands from the commandline you must either escape whitespace characters or encompass them in quotes (I can't remember if you have to use double quotes or not in windows, it's been a while). This is because spaces are treated as separators between arguments. Try

`os.system(r'start " " "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"')`

Answer (score 0):

Trying quotes around the path:

```
os.system('"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe"')
```

Comment: Please do not link to your personal site in an answer unless you are linking to something relevant to the question and including a summary of the information at the destination. Otherwise it will be considered as spam in the future.

Comment: this will also block until finished where I believe in the OP he is expecting it not to block